# React Native - Call Function of child from NavigatorIOS

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to call a child function from the right button on the parent navigator.

A basic code example of what I need is as follows:

Main.js

```
<NavigatorIOS
    style={styles.container}
    initialRoute={{
        title: 'Test',
        component: Test,
        rightButtonTitle: 'Change String',
        onRightButtonPress: () => ***I Want to call miscFunction from here*** ,
        passProps: {
            FBId: this.state.fbidProp,
            favsPage: true
        }
    }}/>
```

Test.js

```
class Test extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            variable: 'some string'
        };
    }
    miscFunction(){
        this.setState({
            variable: 'new string'
        };
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <Text> {variable} </Text>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is covered in the following github issue:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/31

Eric Vicenti comments to describe how Facebook solves this internally:

> Currently the best way to do that is to create an `EventEmitter` in the owner of the `NavigatorIOS`, then you can pass it down to children using `route.passProps`. The child can mix in `Subscribable.Mixin` and then in `componentDidMount`, you can
>
> ```
> this.addListenerOn(this.props.events, 'myRightBtnEvent', this._handleRightBtnPress);
> ```
>
> It is clear that this API needs improvement. We are actively working the routing API in Relay, and hopefully react-router, but we want NavigatorIOS to be usable independently. Maybe we should add an event emitter inside the navigator object, so child components can subscribe to various navigator activity:
>
> ```
> this.addListenerOn(this.props.navigator.events, 'rightButtonPress', this._handleRightBtnPress);
> ```

Here's how this looks in a practical example:

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');
var EventEmitter = require('EventEmitter');
var Subscribable = require('Subscribable');

var {
    AppRegistry,
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    View,
    NavigatorIOS
} = React;
```

First we pull in all of our requirements including the EventEmitter and Subscribable.

```
var App = React.createClass({
    componentWillMount: function() {
        this.eventEmitter = new EventEmitter();
    },

    onRightButtonPress: function() {
        this.eventEmitter.emit('myRightBtnEvent', { someArg: 'argValue' });
    },

    render: function() {
        return <NavigatorIOS
                style={styles.container}
                initialRoute={{
                    title: 'Test',
                    component: Test,
                    rightButtonTitle: 'Change String',
                    onRightButtonPress: this.onRightButtonPress,
                    passProps: {
                        events: this.eventEmitter
                    }
                }}/>
    }
});
```

In our main top-level component, we create a new EventEmitter (in `componentWillMount`) to be available across the component, and then use `passProps` to pass it down to the `Test` component we specify for the navigator.

We also define a handler for the right button press, which emits a `myRightBtnEvent` with some dummy arguments when that button is pressed. Now, in the `Test` component:

```
var Test = React.createClass({
    mixins: [Subscribable.Mixin],

    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            variable: 'original string'
        };
    },

    componentDidMount: function() {
        this.addListenerOn(this.props.events, 'myRightBtnEvent', this.miscFunction);
    },

    miscFunction: function(args){
        this.setState({
            variable: args.someArg
        });
    },
    render: function(){
        return(
            <View style={styles.scene}><Text>{this.state.variable}</Text></View>
        )
    }
});
```

We add the `Subscribable` mixin, and the only other thing we need to do is listen out for the `myRightBtnEvent` being fired from the `App` component and hook `miscFunction` up to it. The `miscFunction` will be passed the dummy arguments from the `App` press handler so we can use those to set state or perform other actions.

You can see a working version of this on RNPlay:

https://rnplay.org/apps/H5mMNQ

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm still a bit of an amateur when it comes to react native. Is EventEmitter part of react-native already or do I need to add it? also not familiar with Subscribable.Mixin

Comment: EventEmitter ships with React Native, and Subscribable leverages it. If you do a search for Subscribable on the React Native github you'll see some examples but I'll try and flesh out my answer when I have more time.

Comment: Added a full example.

Comment: I am struggling to get this example to work with es6. I keep getting this error Uncaught TypeError: this.addListenerOn is not a function

Comment: Have you imported/required subscribable?

Comment: I did but I'm not sure how to write the below line of code as es6
    mixins: [Subscribable.Mixin],

Comment: Oh, es6 doesn't have mixins so I'm not sure either actually.

Comment: Has anyone found out how to do this with ES6? I can't use mixins with the Component class.

Answer (score 0):

A. In initial component

```
this.props.navigator.push({
    title: 'title',
    component: MyComponent,
    rightButtonTitle: 'rightButton',
    passProps: {
        ref: (component) => {this.pushedComponent = component},
    },
    onRightButtonPress: () => {
        // call func
        this.pushedComponent && this.pushedComponent.myFunc();
    },
});
```

B. In pushed component 
replace onRightButtonPress func in pushed component.

```
componentDidMount: function() {
    // get current route
    var route = this.props.navigator.navigationContext.currentRoute;
    // update onRightButtonPress func
    route.onRightButtonPress =  () => {
        // call func in pushed component
        this.myFunc();
    };
    // component will not rerender
    this.props.navigator.replace(route);
},
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [flux](https://facebook.github.io/flux/), here is a demo: https://github.com/backslash112/react-native_flux_demo