# EventEmitter and Subscriber ES6 Syntax with React Native

Tags: react-native, mixins, eventemitter

I am trying to implement an EventEmitter/Subscriber relationship between two components in a react native class. I have seen referenced the following materials:

- [React Native - Event Emitters by Colin Ramsay](https://colinramsay.co.uk/2015/07/04/react-native-eventemitters.html)
- [React Native - Call Function of child from NavigatorIOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31177366/react-native-call-function-of-child-from-navigatorios)

These solutions are adequate for what I am trying to accomplish, however, they bother require the use of `mixins: [Subscribable.Mixin]` on the receiving component to work properly with `Subscriber`. Unfortunately, I am using ES6 and extending my classes from `Component` so I can not use this mixin syntax.

My question is: How can I implement the above solutions in ES6 without the use of mixins?

Comment: Here someone suggests to use simply use the "old way" of writing the component: http://hi-tips.tumblr.com/post/137014836571/use-eventemitter-for-calling-child-component-event

I have the same problem and would like to know if there is any proper way of doing this in ES6

Comment: I'm still looking for this. I'm reluctant to start using `react-mixin`.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You don't need mixins to use EventEmitters.

Simple demo:

```
import EventEmitter from 'EventEmitter';

let x = new EventEmitter();

function handler(arg) {
    console.log(`event-name has occurred! here is the event data arg=${JSON.stringify(arg)}`);
}

x.addListener('event-name', handler);

x.emit('event-name', { es6rules: true, mixinsAreLame: true });
```

The full signature for `addListener` takes three args:

```
EventEmitter.addListener(eventName, handler, handlerContext)
```

In a react component, you likely want to use that context arg, so that the handler can be a class method instead of an inline function and still retain `this == component instance`. E.g.:

```
componentDidMount() {
    someEmitter.addListener('awesome', this.handleAwesomeEvents, this);
    // the generalist suggests the alternative:
    someEmitter.addListener('awesome', this.handleAwesomeEvents.bind(this));
}

handleAwesomeEvents = (event) => {
    let awesomeness = event.awesomeRating;

    // if you don't provide context in didMount,
    // "this" will not refer to the component,
    // and this next line will throw
    this.setState({ awesomeness });
};
```

FYI: I got this from looking at the decidedly unmagical implementation of [the infamous Subscribable mixin](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/235b16d93287061a09c4624e612b5dc4f960ce47/Libraries/Components/Subscribable.js#L59). Google search results are basically an echo chamber of Ramsay's single mixin-based demo.

P.S. As far as exposing this emitter to another component, I'd probably have the owning component provide a function for receiving the emitter reference, and the component that creates the emitter would then conditionally execute that prop with the emitter.

```
// owner's render method:
<ThingThatEmits
    onEmitterReady={(emitter) => this.thingEmitter = emitter}
/>

// inside ThingThatEmits:
componentDidMount() {
    this.emitter = new EventEmitter();

    if(typeof this.props.onEmitterReady === 'function') {
        this.props.onEmitterReady(this.emitter);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you! your 'Simple demo' was exactly what i needed to see for it to click.

Comment: Hi Tom, when I try to call `let test = new EventEmitter();` it throws `undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'new _reactNative.EventEmitter()')` any thought about this?

Comment: @Richard: None. What version of react-native are you using? Are you sure you imported correctly? Have you tried rebooting your RN packager? Is this a build-time or run-time failure?

Comment: I know that is pretty late response, but you should do the import like this `import EventEmitter from "EventEmitter";` not like this `import { EventEmitter } from "EventEmitter";`

Comment: How is what you're doing in the last code snippet different than providing a function from the parent to its children via props?

Answer (score 29):

This might be a very late answer, but I'm just going to put it out there for anyone who might find this useful.

As of the time of writing this answer (July, 2020), React Native has changed a lot since version `0.60.0+`, you can either use an instance of `EventEmitter`, or statically call the `DeviceEventEmitter` methods.

---

Here is an example using `EventEmitter`:

```js
import { EventEmitter } from 'events';

const newEvent = new EventEmitter();

// then you can use: "emit", "on", "once", and "off"
newEvent.on('example.event', () => {
  // ...
});
```

---

Another example using the `DeviceEventEmitter`:

```js
import { DeviceEventEmitter } from 'react-native';

// then you can directly use: "emit", "addListener", and "removeAllListeners"
DeviceEventEmitter.emit('example.event', ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']);
```

Hope that comes handy for anyone who still looking for a way to implement custom events in React Native.

Comment: I like this DeviceEventEmitter I don't have to make a new instance. Thank you!

Comment: DeviceEventEmitter worked fine for me, but still curious why I can't find about it react-native docs

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get a workaround with [react-mixin](https://github.com/brigand/react-mixin). Not sure how proper it is, but it works without any modification. The key is adding `reactMixin(DetailView.prototype, Subscribable.Mixin);` after the class definition.

Going off the example that is floating around for EventEmitter and Subscribable:

```
'use strict';

var reactMixin = require('react-mixin');
var React = require('react-native');
var EventEmitter = require('EventEmitter');
var Subscribable = require('Subscribable');

var {
    AppRegistry,
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    View,
    NavigatorIOS
} = React;

class MainView extends Component {
    constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.EventEmitter = new EventEmitter();
    }

    somethingHappenedFunction(){
      this.EventEmitter.emit("update_event", { message: "hello from up here"});
    }

    //rest of the class
}

class DetailView extends Component {
   componentDidMount(){
     this.addListenerOn(this.props.events, 'update_event', this.miscFunction);
   }

   miscFunction(args) {
    console.log("message: %s", args.message);
   }

   //rest of the class
}
reactMixin(DetailView.prototype, Subscribable.Mixin);
```

Answer (score 0):

With react-native 0.69.0 I solved it like this:

```
import EventEmitter from 'react-native/Libraries/vendor/emitter/EventEmitter';

const emitter = new EventEmitter();

emitter.addListener('event name', (...args) => console.log('emitted with', args));
emitter.emit('event name', { message: 'Foo' });
```